# Validar en la capa de servicio si el nombre de usuario ya existe antes de registrarlo

Tags: java, validación, excepciones, servicio

Si mi base de datos no permite registrar un usuario con un username que ya este almacenado, deberia:

1-validar en la capa de servicio al estilo:

```
public User saveUser(User user){
 if(repoUser.findByUsername(user.getUserName())!=null)
   throw new RuntimeException("username already exists");
  return repoUser.save(user);
}
```

2- capturar la excepción que viene de repoUser en el servicio y lanzarla como excepción de servicio al estilo:

```
public User saveUser(User user){
 try{
  return repoUser.save(user);
 }catch(DAOException e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
 }
}
```

Comment: A más de uno no le gusta usar RuntimeException para propagar cosas y prefieren excepciones personalizadas... en ambos casos te gastas el tiempo de ir hasta la BD y ver si ya está, depende de que efectivamente haya un constraint que valide unicidad por una columna de la tabla, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
 public void saveUser(User user){
    try {
        boolean exist = repoUser.findByUsername(user.getUserName());
        if(!exist){
            repoUser.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new FieldAlreadyExistException("El usuario ya existe");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

`FieldAlreadyExistException` es una excepcion personalizada, te recomiendo implementar un controlador de excepciones.

Utilizar la clase `java.util.logging.Logger` para la gestión de logs en tu aplicacion.

Espero te sea de ayuda.....